# Generate war file without libs directory in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, war

I have a gradle project and configured war plugin that is successfully generating the war file.

I want my dependencies jar files not to be the part of .war file in directory [/WEB-INF/lib/].

I will manually add all the dependencies in jboss's lib folder.

```
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceSets  {
 main {
    java {
        srcDir 'src'
    }
 }
}

war.baseName = 'web'

webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

war {
 webXml = file('WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml')
}

dependencies {
 compile fileTree('../ThirdPartyJars')
 compile project(':core')
}
```

This is generating a .war file that already contains all the dependency.

Is their any way to remove all these dependencies from war file in gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an awful idea, IMO, but you can add the dependencies to the `providedCompile` or `providedRuntime` configuration rather than `compile` or `runtime`.

Comment: Thanks! providedCompile worked for me. I know its a bad idea to have all the dependencies in jboss libs, but its a legacy project I am working on a lot of dependencies already present in jboss that i can't remove due to other projects using these.

Comment: If we include dependencies in the .war file, then total size of the file become more than 100 MB that takes time to move deploy able war to other servers in jboss deploy directory. Is their any alternative to this approach as you said having dependencies inside a war is bad idea.